# flyway from maven: getting Datasource not set! error

Tags: mysql, maven, flyway

I am trying to use flyway from maven and I have pom that looks like this with regard to flyway:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>migrate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <user>jrm</user>
                                <password></password>
                                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/fooDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</url>
                                <table>version_history</table>
                                <locations>
                                    <location>
                                        filesystem:../../scripts/entitlement/db/cd
                                    </location>
                                </locations>
```

Note that the jrm user requires no password but I have gotten the same result with users that have a non-null password. On Windows I can use MySQL command line client to log into the db. My impression of this message is that it indicates something is wrong with the authentication; using flyway version 4.0.3 it says to check user, password and url.

I believe this might be Windows specific problem. Note that I have add the MySQL bin to the path environment variable. I note that I am not prompted for a password when I try mysql -u root, I just get access denied unless I use mysql -u root -p and I have some reason to believe that I needed a user that therefore had a null password.

EDIT: I am using mvn flyway:migrate

Comment: the plugin may not read the configuration if you execute the goal directly. the configuration as it is in your pom is bound to an execution. does it work when you run "mvn compile"?

Comment: Holy cow, that worked. Tables created! Thanks very much, wemu!!

Comment: Ah so the guess was good :) - if you still want to run the flyway goal directly you can simply move the <configuration> on the level where the <groupId> and is. Then every execution will use that configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers given by wemu are completely correct: it was necessary, as the pom is currently written, to do mvn compile rather than flyway:migrate. Moreover, wemu's subsequent suggestion about moving the configuration should make it possible to invoke Flyway directly which is probably the correct way to do things. I guess the error messages from the Flyway plugin are completely accurate: it did not see the authorization/db access configuration but I did not know enough about Maven to understand why and spent significant time thinking the info was wrong not merely unavailable to the plugin.